# How to integrate Gradle into IntelliJ IDEA in a Flutter project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, settings

I've created a Flutter project in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3 (Ultimate Edition, Build #IU-203.7717.56). When I open a Gradle file (e.g: `android/settings.gradle`), the IDE complains about not being able to *"resolve some symbols"*:

```
def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
//                            ^^^^
//                            Cannot resolve symbol 'File'

def properties = new Properties()
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^
//                   Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'
```

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Gradle integration issue: Cannot resolve symbol]

So, how to help IntelliJ IDEA with this issue? *(to have the powerful IDE help us later on :)*

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Comment: @y.bedrov The issue is with the IDE and is independent of any project; The Flutter projects work just fine (so does the Gradle, of course). Only, the IDE needs to be somehow provided with the Gradle components to stop complaining and get happy once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your libraries have been added correctly. It usually means that IntelliJ cannot resolve the references to it; it first searches in your code, then your libraries.

[Refer to this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29608#issuecomment-548649907)